# Let $f:ℝ→ℕ$ be onto. Does there exist a $g:ℕ→ℝ$ such that $f(g(b))=b$ for all $b∈ℕ$?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I'm reading Classic Set Theory for Guided Independent Study, and they introduced ZF set theory (no axiom of choice still) and the construction of integers, real, rational and natural numbers. The books says that it's impossible to describe, finitely, a way of obtaining $g(b)$ for each $b∈ℕ$, but i can't see why. If i let $f(x)=x$ and $g(b)=b$ we would have $f(g(b))=g(b)=b$ why wouldn't this work?

Thank you!

Comment: What you wrote is not clear.  You wrote $b=f(x)=x$ but why should $f(x)=x$? If $x\notin \mathbb N$ then $f(x)=x$ isn't even possible. And as to $b=f(x)$...well, which $b$ do you choose?  There could be uncountably many options.

Comment: @lulu actually i got pretty confused as well, what i would like to do is to make a function $f$ that  maps $1$ into $1$, $2$ into $2$ and so on, and make $g$ do the same. so when you calculate $f(g(b))$ you obtain again the same element

Comment: But it's not up to you to "make" the function $f$, it is already given to you.  Indeed, there are some functions $f$ for which a suitable $g$ is easy to construct.  If, say, $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ then $g(n)=n$ will work.  But solving the problem for one particular $f$ is not the same as solving it in general.

Comment: @lull how it's not up to me to make $f$, the book even says "although the domain and codomain of $f$ are specified, the rule of $f$ is essentially arbitrary. To a large extent we are bound to run into problems precisely because the rule of the original function $f$ is so arbitrary." I dont get it

Comment: But that is the entire point.  There is no "universal" way to construct a suitable $g$ given some function $f$.  The fact that you can do it sometimes isn't good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complement to Asaf's answer.  Your problem here might be more about English than mathematics.  (I mean English as used in mathematics which takes some learning even for native English speakers.)

An analogy might help.  Suppose I claim that given a positive real number, I can calculate its square root.  I "prove" this ability by saying that the square root of $4$ is $2$.  Have I proved the ability that I claimed?

You have done the same.  You have found a $g$ for a specific $f$ but not proved your ability to do it for any $f$.

Comment: Ooh here you go, that's what i was thinking, I got confused because it just says "let $f$..." and not the whole "for all $f$..there exists.." thank you!

Comment: It is a common question format and "let $x$ be a blah, blah, blah ..." should be read as "For all $x$ with the properties blah, blah, blab ...".

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, thank you, i've always read this kind of sentence as "if.. then.." sentences. They should really make a book explaining how to translate from math to english since it's always used and never explained

Comment: Such a book may exist but I don't know of one. I think that most of us learn but being told off by an instructor.  It would be useful.

Comment: Yeah I'm actually an engineering student but i'm studying math on the side since i think college is pretty useless..(4 months to learn analysis, mechanics, electromagnetism, linear algebra, abstract algebra and combinatorics all at the same time.. I'm pretty sure people just learn the tip of it..)

Answer (score 4):

No.

This is equivalent to the statement "Given any countable family of pairwise disjoint sets of real numbers, there is a choice function". Such thing, for example, would imply that every subset of the real numbers is finite or has a countably infinite subset.

This was shown to be unprovable from $\sf ZF$ by Cohen, and is now one of the most important models of $\sf ZF+\lnot AC$, also known as "Cohen's first model".

There are other constructions that would make it even more explicit where and how a counterexample could consistently exist. But to truly appreciate that, you'd need to first understand set theory in general, forcing, and symmetric extensions.

Comment: I don't know what a choice function is though since I still haven't studied the axiom of choice, could you please explain in other words?